# Joining 2 arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am dealing with an API that only lets me access data by month. Occasionally, the data spans over 2 months, but there is no easy test to check against that.

I am already looping over the result data to find the data I need. I figure I can just call the API twice, for both months, and append 1 month onto the other.

I am trying to figure out how to join the 2 arrays together. Heres an example, I have:

```
firstMonth = array(0 => object0, 1 => object1, 2 => object2)
secondMonth = array(0 => object3, 1 => object4, 2 => object5)
```

and I need to join them so I have one array, like:

```
bothMonths = array(0 => object 0, 1 => object1, 2 => object2, 3 => object3, 4 => object4, 5 => object5)
```

So, how can I join my 2 arrays?

Comment: @BookOfZeus: this won't help, I think you meant array_merge

Comment: oh yeah! i misread the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`array_merge();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to achieve this. Use + when you have different indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function zip() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    $zipped = array();
    $n = count($args);
    for ($i=0; $i<$n; ++$i) {
        reset($args[$i]);
    }
    while ($n) {
        $tmp = array();
        for ($i=0; $i<$n; ++$i) {
            if (key($args[$i]) === null) {
                break 2;
            }
            $tmp[] = current($args[$i]);
            next($args[$i]);
        }
        $zipped[] = $tmp;
    }
    return $zipped;
}

$bothMonths = zip($firstMonth, $secondMonth);

print_r($bothMonths);
```

Similar to the ruby/python/haskell/... zip function, which is what you want

Answer (score -2):

Use PHP's [`array_merge`](http://php.net/array_merge) function:

```
 $bothMonths = array_merge($firstMonth, $secondMonth);
```

Comment: I'm confused. isn't that exactly what you said above, just with an example?

Comment: It is now. Before the post was edited, they suggested you use [Array Union](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php)